# Firebase inicio de sesión con varias redes sociales Android Studio (APIS redes sociales)

Tags: android-studio, firebase, facebook-api, twitter-api, instagram-api

Estoy intentando hacer que los usuarios de mi aplicación accedan a sus redes sociales de forma que puedan interactuar con ellas desde mi aplicación, es decir un funcionamiento similar a hootsuite.

De momento se registran en la aplicación con `firebaseUI`. Pero necesito que una vez estén logueados en mi aplicación, puedan loguearse en todas sus redes sociales e interactuar con ellas desde dentro.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? No sabría por donde empezar, agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda o de guía.

Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La autenticación de Firebase con FirebaseUI por defecto solo pide los permisos básicos para hacer el login, en caso de querer interactuar con las redes vas a tener que sumar otros alcances (scopes) para que el usuario acceda a eso al momento de hacer el login.

Una vez que tienes el login con Firebase, puedes [acceder al token de OAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getIdToken(boolean)) que te habilita a llamar a los servicios en nombre del usuario.

Comment: Hola, entiendo mas o menos el funcionamiento, si conoces alguna guía fuera de la documentación, te agradecería el enlace. Quizás el inconveniente que le veo a obtener el token después del login es que no se como se podría interactuar con todas las redes a la vez. Disculpa si no lo he comprendido bien, estoy empezando a utilizar APIs y voy muy perdido con su funcionamiento

Comment: cada red tiene su API con sus reglas y permisos, vas a tener que leer la documentación de todas para poder incluirlas.